# Skin Texture Inpainting

Tags: opengl, machine-learning, blender, opengl-3, render-to-texture

As a part of my project, I wish to build a product that takes as Input, Mesh Objects and textures of some regions of the objects(as of now objects are Humans), and the job of the product is to somehow predict what will be the texture of the regions where no texture was given in the Input. I am not able to decide as to where to begin from ? Basically, the job of the product is to predict textures and since all this needs to be automated, I need to write codes/scipts but I need to know what all software technologies are required ? Any references to previous work in this field ? (I have already googled for a lot of time).

Comment: One of the easiest you can try is Gabor filters: chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/http://www.cse.iitm.ac.in/~vplab/courses/CV_DIP/PDF/Lect-Gabor_filt.pdf . I would suggest to use Matlab if you can otherwise use python

Answer (score 0):

ehm in blender texture depends on UV unwrapping. 
If you take a human shape it depends on how one unwraps the model so a texture will fit. I can create various unwrap UV models, in fact the possibilities are endless. unless you deal with a somewhat fixed layout (ea seccond life or so). this almost not solvable i think.

Its very clear in blender to see where there is no texture, there you'll see the backgrond (the background of the image with the texture).

In most cases where you see something of a miss alligned texture often the texture is completely wrong out of place, and so it would be extreme hard to solve. Best you might do is not putting a texture on shape at all, but for your logic check texture with existing textures of that object and see if everything is covered, but that will only work with fixed unwrap models, ea second life.

without standard for that, you'll have a problem as complex as understanding a natural language, and speaking it. computers dont know a lot, neural networks can eumlate to know things, but its even beyond me to understand them.